# making a list of items combining each item from several lists

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a module for Pygame which does video effects with texts like fade in, fade out, zoom in,zoom out, rotate etc. The program works fine. I want to write a demo highlighting all posibilities of the module. All effects are as below.

```
import copy

zoom = ["in", "out"]
fade = ["in", "out"]
rotate = ["left", "right"]
slide = ["in left", "in right", "in top", "in bottom","out left", "out right", "out top", "out bottom"]
```

I need each effect in each type to join up with each effect in all other types WITH THE EXCEPTION OF zoom in fade out and zoom out fade in which doesn't make much sense  visually. I need these effects, which will be four to a group, in the order zoom, fade, rotate, slide, in separate lists in a particular format (temp = [None, None, None, None]. If there is no effect in a slot it will be None. An example is given below.

```
(zoom = "out", rotate = "left", fade = "out", slide = "out top")
```

This is the code I got so far.

```
functions_main = [zoom, fade, rotate, slide]
function_list = []
temp = [None,
for count, item in enumerate(functions_main):
    for part in item:
        t = copy.copy(temp)
        t[count] = part
        function_list.append(t)
```

This gives me each item once in each group. as shown below.

```
['in', None, None, None]
['out', None, None, None]
[None, 'in', None, None]
[None, 'out', None, None]
[None, None, 'left', None]
[None, None, 'right', None]
```

etc. etc. 
 How do I get the rest of the items in? For instance Zoom in, fade in, rotate left, NO slide would be `("in", "in", "left", None)`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would want all possible combinations? If yes, check this out https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: I tried it but maybe not correctly so was undecided. I will give it a shot. Thanks for pointing in the right direction and clearing my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being nudged in the right direction by  https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca I figured out the easiest way to do this was to use itertools.

```
mylist = list(itertools.product(funcs[item[0]], funcs[item[1]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `None` to each list to make combining easier:

```
zoom = ["in", "out", None]
fade = ["in", "out", None]
rotate = ["left", "right", None]
slide = ["in left", "in right", "in top", "in bottom","out left", "out right", "out top", "out bottom", None]

result = [[i, j, k, l] for i in zoom for j in fade for k in rotate for l in slide if not ((i == 'in' and j == 'out') or (j == 'in' and i == 'out'))]
```